# Why doesn't (&mut iter).take(n) take ownership of iter?

Tags: rust, ownership

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=27451eb0a114417afcea5b6c53a92ff2

In this code:

```rust
fn main() {
    let my_vec = vec![1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
    let mut pair: Vec<Vec<u8>> = vec![vec![], vec![]];
    
    let mut my_vec_iter = my_vec.into_iter();
    // pair.iter_mut().for_each(|v| v.append(&mut my_vec_iter.take(4).collect()));
    // error[E0507]: cannot move out of `my_vec_iter`, a captured variable in an `FnMut` closure
    
    let my_ref = &mut my_vec_iter;
    pair.iter_mut().for_each(|v| v.append(&mut my_ref.take(4).collect()));
    
    println!("{:?}", pair);
}
```

The commented-out line doesn't compile, because (as I understand it) `take()` takes ownership of its receiver and you can't do that with a captured variable.

But the alternative version, where the captured variable is `&mut my_vec_iter`, *does* work, and I don't understand what's going on. I haven't been able to find a version of `take(&mut self)`, so presumably it's still calling `take(self)`?

Explain like I'm 5 - how come taking an explicit mutable reference stops `take` taking ownership? Or, if I've misunderstood something, what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works because `Iterator` is also implemented for references with [this impl](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#impl-Iterator-for-%26mut+I).

```rs
impl<I> Iterator for &mut I
where
    I: Iterator + ?Sized,
```

`Iterator::take` always takes `self`, but you can use either `I` or `&mut I` as the type of `self`.

There's also a convenience method on `Iterator` just for obtaining a `&mut self` reference, so you don't need to make another binding or contend with operator precedence: [`Iterator::by_ref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.by_ref).

```rs
// these are identical

my_vec_iter.by_ref().take(4)

(&mut my_vec_iter).take(4)
```

You should also use `extend` when appending from an iterator. This avoids allocating a temporary `Vec`.

```rs
pair.iter_mut().for_each(|v| v.extend(my_vec_iter.by_ref().take(4)));
```

Comment: Hang on, wait. In the mut-ref version of my code, `my_ref` is presumably still captured by the closure, and `take` is still going to take ownership of `my_ref` (just not the underlying `my_vec_iter`). Why is that allowed?

Comment: @Chowlett when you call a function that takes `&mut`, the argument is automatically reborrowed. If you expanded that out, it would look like `Iterator::take(&mut *my_ref, 4)`. So really, `my_ref` is giving out a new temporary `&mut` every time you call `take` instead of being consumed.

Comment: Ah, that's neat. Is there somewhere I could have found that in docs?

Comment: @Chowlett [apparently not](https://github.com/rust-lang/reference/issues/788)